# How to send date within an input date control with onkeydown="return false" using Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, date, selenium-webdriver, onkeydown

I have this minimal html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="date" max="2023-03-09" value="2023-03-09" onkeydown="return false">
    </body>
</html>
```

That just asks for a date, but `onkeydown="return false"` prevents keyboard input. So I have to navigate the (I guess browser-generated) calendar, but don't know how to access it. Even the calendar icon in the control is difficult to access. I have resorted to clicking with a fixed offset, but maybe there's a better way.

My minimal python code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("E:\\Web\\TestDate\\public_html\\index.html")
buttonDate = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
action = ActionChains(driver)
w, h = buttonDate.size['width'], buttonDate.size['height']
x, y = buttonDate.location['x'], buttonDate.location['y']
wx, wy = driver.get_window_size()['width'], driver.get_window_size()['height']
action.move_to_element_with_offset(buttonDate, w - 10, h - 7)
action.click()
action.perform()
time.sleep(30)
driver.quit()
```

With that I can get the calendar control open, but cannot use `send_keys()` to change the date.

Edit: Thanks for all the answers, you all saved me. I have accepted the shortest, most general purpose one, even if all were good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Selenium's `execute_script` method to run `JavaScript` and pass the text into the desired textbox. Refer the code below:

```
date= "2023-03-09"
input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='date']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', input_box, date)
```

**Note:** This is like inserting the text into the web page from backend. This solution won't imitate the human actions as selenium's `send_keys` does.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the event handler

```py
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('input[type=\"date\"]').onkeydown = () => {}")
```

Javascript code

```js
document.querySelector('input[type="date"]').onkeydown = () => {}
```

full code such as

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("E:\\Web\\TestDate\\public_html\\index.html")
buttonDate = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")

# Call Javascript Here.
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('input[type=\"date\"]').onkeydown = () => {}")

# Now send the keys here to the element
buttonDate.send_keys("20230629")

action = ActionChains(driver)

time.sleep(30)
driver.quit()
```

Online Test via [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/92cy3bqL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Given the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="date" max="2023-03-09" value="2023-03-09" onkeydown="return false">
    </body>
</html>
```

To send a customized date you can use the [`removeAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577612/7429447) method to remove the **onkeydown** attribute and invoke `send_keys()` as follows:

```
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/fname.lname/Desktop/My%20Documents/Selenium/date.html")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('onkeydown')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='date']"))))
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='date']").send_keys("29062023")
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: 29062023]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on date in zebra datepicker in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577612/7429447)
- [How to send a date directly as text to a calendar control with readonly attribute using Selenium through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57453876/7429447)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JS `setAttribute()` function to change the date directly:

```py
script = (
    """document.querySelector('%s').setAttribute('%s','%s');"""
    % ('input[type="date"]', "value", "2023-06-29")
)
driver.execute_script(script)
```